# Split with lines not fully working using QGIS

Tags: qgis, splitting

I'm using QGIS 3.8 and I've got two shapefiles which I would like to cut in pieces using Split with lines

Both times I used the algorithm the first two lines did not cut through my shapes, while the rest of the shape is properly cut in pieces.

Is this is a bug that someone else has experienced?

Here are some pictures of my problem:

[image: picture1]

[image: picture2]

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to include Well-Known Text for the polygon and the first four lines for at least one of your diagrams

Comment: @Vince I do not fully understand what you would like me to edit. Could you please elaborate your question.

Comment: Well-Known Text (aka WKT) is an ASCII representation for geometry. If you include the geometry in the question, others can review the data and attempt to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Joseph Thanks, this solved the issue!

Answer (score 8):

It's quite likely to be a bug as I have experienced something similar, I would suggest you [post a ticket on their GitHub page](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues).

In the meantime, a possible workaround is to **dissolve** your line layer so that it contains a single line feature and then use this with the `Split with lines` tool.

Comment: This did not help me... 1 line, 1 polygon, same CRS, complete intersection. No error message, no cut.