# Split with Lines not splitting polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, splitting

Split with Lines does not appear to be working for me in QGIS 3.24.

[image]

My line and polygon are in the same CRS, you can see that they completely intersect but when I get the results, the polygon is unsplit (the layer has a single polygon).

A similar post at [Split with lines not fully working using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332075) suggests dissolving, but this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what went wrong. The line was listed as one feature and was created in a continuous fashion. However, when I tried copying to the new scratch file, it pasted as 5 separate lines. I had tried dissolving my previous line without success. But when I dissolved these in my new shapefile and reperformed the split, it finally worked. So, I guess the issue was discontinuities hidden by a corrupted shapefile.

Comment: Should I keep this post?

Comment: It’s your choice but personally I think deleting the answer and then the question might be appropriate.

Comment: @PolyGeo I don't see how deleting the answer and keeping the question would be appropriate since the answer gives my best approximation of what was wrong and a possible solution. On one hand, it might lead people with similar issues astray unless they have a similar corruption. On the other hand, perhaps my solution suggests a troubleshooting method for other users who can't snip due to hidden breaks in their line(s). I would have appreciated finding such an answer that would have got me troubleshooting in my situation. I now have another trick up my sleeve for future issues.

Comment: I suggested deleting both answer and question which I think *may* need to be done in that order.